# Elasticsearch - How to filter aggregation with nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to filter nested aggregation but filter doesn't
work. I tried to add a filter to different aggregation levels but it
still doesn't work It return me values with other
participant_type_group_id (not 2). Thank you for your help.

I'm using this query and aggregation definition:

````
{
  "aggs": {
            "agg_by_type_id": {
              "aggs": {
                "agg_by_type_id": {
                  "aggs": {
                    "reverse_nested_type_id": {
                      "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "nested": {
                                "path": "info",
                                "query": {
                                  "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                        "term": {
                                          "info.type_group_id": {
                                            "value": 2
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }]}}}}]}
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "FILTERED": {
                          "aggs": {
                            "inner_docs": {
                              "terms": {
                                "field": "info.type_id",
                                "size": 10000
                              }}},
                          "reverse_nested": {}
                        }}}},
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "info.type_id",
                    "size": 10000
                  }
                }
              },
              "nested": {
                "path": "info"
              }
            }
        }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "info",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "info.type_group_id": {
                        "value": 2
                      }
                    } }]}}}} ]}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: You query is not valid JSON, can you check?

Comment: Sorry:

"query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": [
    {
     "nested": {
      "path": "info",
      "query": {
       "bool": {
        "must": [
         {
          "term": {
           "info.type_group_id": {
            "value": 2
           }
          }
         }
        ]
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }

Comment: Not in comments, please update the full query in your question and properly indent it (i.e. make it legible) please ;-)